# How to integrate ad mob ads in cocos2d android portal?

Tags: android, cocos2d

Could anybody tell me how to integrate ad mob ads in my cocos2d android app.

Comment: What have you tried already? Why didn't it work? -1 for not showing any research effort.

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm sure you've already tried the [official tutorial](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/android/fundamentals). And have done a basic Google search and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582765/good-resource-for-android-admob-tutorial) and [this](http://www.basic4ppc.com/forum/basic4android-getting-started-tutorials/7300-admob-tutorial-add-ads-your-application.html) and [this video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ll8uYcH6Ex8) and [this tutorial](http://www.taiic.com/2011/04/12/admob-tutorial-using-admob-sdk/). I think you may have to provide more detail about a specific problem you've come across.

Comment: Thank you for giving answer. Yes i have tried it is working in normal android aap but i don't have any idea how to add it in android game engine cocos2d ?